# Is it possible to execute javascript from console between pages?

Tags: javascript, console

I am trying to solve this issue and can’t seem to find any answers on the web or anywhere. The task is simple. I am using console in Chrome and I am trying to execute Javascript code that will execute the code between pages. As a simple example trying to navigate and pause between pages seems like impossible task.

```js
var increment = 1;
var miliseconds = 2500;
setTimeout(function () {window.open('www.google.com', '_self');}, miliseconds * increment);increment++; 

// Do something or grab values on this page
setTimeout(function () {window.open('www.yahoo.com', '_self');}, miliseconds * increment);increment++;

// Do something or grab values on this page
setTimeout(function () {window.open('www.cnn.com', '_self');}, miliseconds * increment);increment++;
```

Tried event listeners and no luck. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not possible. The console's environment will clear every time you navigate. The most you can do is preserve logs, but that will not allow you to continue executing JS defined on the previous page.

The only way I know of to persist values accross pages is to use the [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/name) variable which will remain accross different pages, but this is pretty hacky.

If you're looking for something a bit more permanent, I would recommend writing a chrome plugin instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Do you have an example using window.name variable? Hacky is what I am trying to do anyway.